# How to merge web.config of packages with web deploy (msdeploy)?

Tags: asp.net, webdeploy

These are the steps I performed:

1. Created two packages: `Package.zip` and `CustomisePackage.zip` using msdeploy.
2. Deployed first package `Package.zip` to the destination site e.g: site/WebDeployment.
3. Deployed second package `CustomisePackage.zip` to the same destination site. e.g: site/WebDeployment. Skip web.config to be overwritten.

My question is how can I merge web.config from `CustomisePackage.zip` to the site (site/WebDeployment)?

Does anyone have the same sort of scenario and have the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create different config files for different environment. Before deploying transform your file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd465318%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx

And if you are specifically looking to merge the file after copy the second package at the same location then you should merge tool like [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/)

Comment: To use merge tool, firstly i have to extract (CustomisePackage.zip) into some folder then i can use merge tool.